# Diferença no tamanho da string com FontMetrics.charWidth e FontMetrics.stringWidth

Tags: java, string

Não estou conseguindo entender o seguinte código:

```
String text = "C JEA NAV/NAP GRV NAV/ELT NAV SOLA PVC EXP PRETO ";    
int posString = FONT_METRICS.stringWidth(text);
int posChar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
     Character character = text.charAt(i);
     posChar += FONT_METRICS.charWidth(character);
}
System.out.println("String: " + posString + " Char: " + posChar);
```

Por que o posString é 198 e o posChar é 207?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
charWidth(char ch)
Returns the advance width of the specified character in this Font.

stringWidth(String str)
Returns the total advance width for showing the specified String in this Font.
```

O avanço de um String é a distância ao longo da linha de base do String. Essa distância é a largura que deve ser usada para a centralização ou alinhamento à direita da String.

Note-se que o avanço de uma String não é necessariamente a soma dos avanços de seus caracteres medidos isoladamente porque a largura de um caracter pode variar de acordo com seu contexto.

Por exemplo, em texto árabe, a forma de um caracter pode mudar para se "conectar" a outros caracteres. Além disso, em alguns scripts, certas sequências de caracteres podem ser representadas por uma única forma, chamada de ligadura. A medição de caracteres individualmente não é responsável por essas transformações.

[image: FontMetrics]

Fonte:

[Class FontMetrics - Docs Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html)